# Does using Sleep() in the timer callback function can cause problems in C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I have a question regarding timers and Sleep. I am creating a UI with MFC and I have set a timer for a particular dialog of 200ms. So each 200ms the OnTimer function is called. In this function, I included the function Sleep(50). So here would be a simplification of the code.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MainDialog, CDialog)
  ...
  ON_WM_TIMER()
  ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL MainDialog::OnInitDialog() {
   ...
   SetTimer(1, 200, NULL);
   ...
}

void MainDialog::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent) {
  ...
  Sleep(50)
  ...
}
```

So would this code cause any potential problems or troubles? And also with the sleep function does the OnTimer will be called again after 150ms after the whole execution of OnTimer or 200ms after execution of OnTimer function. I am asking this because my code contains a bug and would like to know if this could be the source of it. Thanks in advance for the precious help.

Comment: That sounds silly. Why would you do that - what problem is it supposed to solve? Timer will fire (roughly) every 200 milliseconds, regardless of the Sleep, if the UI thread is ready to generate the event.

Comment: To simplify I need to write data to a USB device and this one answers me back with the data I need. The read and write are done in two different threads and store the data in a global buffer thus I approximately wait 50ms before having the answer stored from the device in the buffer and this data is necessary for the next tasks in the timer function. I probably can do it in another way but was wondering if this behavior would delay next timer interruption or would do some other effect.

Comment: Message your UI from those other threads when it can update, do not sleep in UI message handlers.

Comment: "*The read and write are done in two different threads and store the data in a global buffer thus I approximately wait 50ms before having the answer stored from the device in the buffer and this data is necessary for the next tasks in the timer function*" - don't use sleeps to coordinate operations like that. Use waitable synchronization instead, like Events, Condition Variables, etc. This is a classic producer/consumer situation, there are plenty of viable solutions readily available for handling that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) sleep command inside a GUI, a dialog in your case, will make your interface sluggish, so avoid using it.

2) OnTimer member function, in your case, will be called approx every 200ms of clock tick. However, if the duration of execution of the function OnTimer() exceeds 200ms, timer will be call again right after the earlier call completes, leading to false timing.

3) OnTimer() is not accurate for time critical works, use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock based instead.

Comment: "*However,if the duration of execution of the function OnTimer() exceeds 200ms, timer will call again before the earlier call completes, leading to false timing.*" - that is not true. The OS simply signals a flag in the message queue when the timer elapses, the corresponding `WM_TIMER` message is not generated until the message queue is pumped and no other higher priority messages are pending. So `OnTimer` will NOT be called again until `OnTimer` exits and execution flow returns to the message loop. Unless your `OnTimer` code pumps the message queue for new messages (which it shouldn't do).

Comment: Mandatory reading: [If my WM_TIMER handler takes longer than the timer period, will my queue fill up with WM_TIMER messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141204-00/?p=43473)

Comment: Also, [system_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) is the wrong clock to use when proper timing is needed. It is not guaranteed to be steady, and can be adjusted at any time. Instead, use a [high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) or [steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Thanks . Edited

Comment: @IInspectable: Edited. Thanks